# SignalR & Autofac - Redis backplane scaleout

Tags: dependency-injection, redis, signalr, autofac, signalr-backplane

I have the following situation: I have a SignalR application in which I use Autofac as a dependency resolver.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    { 
        var container = new AutofacContainer().Container;

        var resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
        resolver.UseRedis("serverIp", portNumber, "password", "channelName");

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
        {
            Resolver = resolver
        });

        resolver.UseRedis("192.168.122.213", 6300, "", "FLEDGG");
        AddSignalRInjection(container, resolver);
    }

    private void AddSignalRInjection(IContainer container,IDependencyResolver resolver)
    {
        var updater = new ContainerBuilder();

        updater.RegisterInstance(resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>());
        updater.Update(container);
    }
}
```

And this is the `AutofacContainer` class.

```
public class AutofacContainer
{
    public IContainer Container { get; set; }
    public AutofacContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .PropertiesAutowired();
        builder.RegisterType<Test>()
            .As<ITest>()
            .PropertiesAutowired();

        Container = builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Now, [the official SignalR Redis scaleout documentation from Microsoft](http://GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(%22server%22,%20port,%20%22password%22,%20%22AppName%22);) states that I should tell the `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver` to `UseRedis`.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis("server", port, "password", "AppName");
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
```

Since I don't use `GlobalHost` anymore in the application (even if I use `GlobalHost` there is absolutely no behavior in Redis) ([as the Autofac integration with SignalR and Owin indicates](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/signalr.html)):

> A common error in OWIN integration is use of the GlobalHost. In OWIN
>   you create the configuration from scratch. You should not reference
>   GlobalHost anywhere when using the OWIN integration.

As the `Startup` class is configured right now:

```
var resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
resolver.UseRedis("serverIp", portNumber, "password", "channelName");
```

so I create a new `resolver` of type `AutofacDependencyResolver` and it connects successfully to the Redis PubSub. The issue however is that if I try to send a single message, that message will repeat itself thousands of times.

(In the Chrome console, for sending a single message from the server I end up in an infinite loop and the client receives it infinitely number of times).

So,  the question is: How do I setup SignalR Redis scaleout while using Autofac as dependency resolver (note: there is no circumstance where I can use another dependency resover).

Thanks!

EDIT: If you want further information about the solution, [here is the repo](https://github.com/radu-matei/SignalRDependencyInjection) without this line:

```
resolver.UseRedis("serverIp", portNumber, "password", "channelName");
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I feel like I should clarify some things: If I use `resolver.UseRedis();`, every message that would be normally sent (once) gets sent many times - so if I subscribe to "channelName" in Redis using `subscribe "channelName"`, I find it to be consistent with the behavior on the client: each message gets sent multiple times.

The next thing to do is have a basic SignalR application without Autofac and see how Redis behaves, although I feel it is an Autofac related issue,  more specifically related with the configuration.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Apparently, there is the same behavior in a basic SignalR app without Autofac. The issue has nothing to do with Autofac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was going on:

The Redis server I was using was configured to have multiple instances running together in a cluster.

By default, if you have a Redis cluster and publish a message on a channel on any instance, that message will  be forwarded by default on all other instance.

> In a Redis Cluster clients can subscribe to every node, and can also
>   publish to every other node. The cluster will make sure that published
>   messages are forwarded as needed. The current implementation will
>   simply broadcast each published message to all other nodes.

[The Redis cluster specification.](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec)

Most likely, the SignalR implementation is configured to take any message coming from Redis, therefore my strange behavior.

The solution is to have a Redis instance that is not in a cluster and everything works fine.

If you want to have a SignalR backplane, don't use an instance from a cluster!